# Spring4d interface-based collection lifecycle

Tags: delphi, spring4d

How do the interface-based collections in spring4d handle the lifecycle of their elements? What I would like to achieve is that when the collection gets out of scope, the containing objects are also freed, and their destructors called. Not sure this is the case at the moment.

Comment: For instance, https://spring4d.4delphi.com/docs/master/Html/index.htm?Spring.Collections.TCollections.CreateObjectList(T)(T[],Boolean).htm

Comment: Thanks for the link. If you add it as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`TCollections`](https://spring4d.4delphi.com/docs/master/Html/index.htm?Spring.Collections.TCollections_Methods.htm) class offers a number of class methods to create new collections. These methods provide parameters that allow you to specify how the member lifetime is to be handled.

- [`CreateDictionary`](https://spring4d.4delphi.com/docs/master/Html/index.htm?Spring.Collections.TCollections.CreateDictionary(TKey,TValue)(TDictionaryOwnerships,Integer).htm) and [`CreateMultiMap`](https://spring4d.4delphi.com/docs/master/Html/index.htm?Spring.Collections.TCollections.CreateMultiMap(TKey,TValue)(TDictionaryOwnerships).htm) have an `ownerships` parameter that allows you to specify that the keys, or values, or both are owned by the collection.
- [`CreateList`](https://spring4d.4delphi.com/docs/master/Html/index.htm?Spring.Collections.TCollections.CreateList(T)(Boolean).htm), [`CreateObjectList`](https://spring4d.4delphi.com/docs/master/Html/index.htm?Spring.Collections.TCollections.CreateObjectList(T)(T[],Boolean).htm), [`CreateSortedList`](https://spring4d.4delphi.com/docs/master/Html/index.htm?Spring.Collections.TCollections.CreateSortedList(T)(Boolean).htm), [`CreateSortedObjectList`](https://spring4d.4delphi.com/docs/master/Html/index.htm?Spring.Collections.TCollections.CreateSortedObjectList(T)(Boolean).htm), [`CreateQueue`](https://spring4d.4delphi.com/docs/master/Html/index.htm?Spring.Collections.TCollections.CreateQueue(T)(Boolean).htm) and [`CreateStack`](https://spring4d.4delphi.com/docs/master/Html/index.htm?Spring.Collections.TCollections.CreateStack(T)(Boolean).htm) have an `ownsObjects` parameter that determines whether or not the collection owns its members.