# Searching for TObjectDictionary in Spring4D Framework

Tags: dictionary, delphi, spring4d

I'am staring to use the Spring4D Framework for Delphi because of its Collections methods that delivers interfaces and all sort of other cool stuff.

I was wondering If there is a Interface I can use, when I need a Dictionary with a Class and that Dictionary should free the classes. Lets say Tdictionary<String,TMyClass>.
How can I get my interface to free up TMyClass when the Dictionary goes out of scope?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851664/spring4d-interface-based-collection-lifecycle I would close as a dupe, but, strike

Comment: Hi David,
Thanks for your great answer. Do you have a Working code Snippet for me?
I tryed: Notifications := TCollections.CreateDictionary<string,TNotification>(DoOwnsValues);
But Compiler says that there is no overloaded Function of CreateDictionary.

Comment: I'm sure you can read the source code for spring and work this out

Comment: Thanks, like TTDictionaryOwnershipS suggested, it can take multiple values here. So I put it in square brackets and it Works:
Notifications := TCollections.CreateDictionary<string,TNotification>([DoOwnsValues]);